# Problem with adding library to modular JavaFX Program in VS Code

Tags: module, jar, pom.xml

I am having a problem trying to integrate the jsch-0.1.55.jar file into my JavaFX project.

I have integrated other jar files, but for some reason, this one won't integrate into the project without giving me errors.

I am using Maven and modular

To add the jcraft.jsch functionality to this project, here is what I did:

Added the dependency to the pom.xml file

```
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is the full pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rheem</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecotool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fazecast</groupId>
            <artifactId>jSerialComm</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.rheem.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Added the following line to the modules-info.java file:

```
   requires com.jcraft.jsch;
```

Here is the full module-info.java file

```
module com.mycompany {
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.fazecast.jSerialComm;
    requires java.logging;
    requires com.jcraft.jsch;

    opens com.mycompany to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mycompany;
}
```

No errors with the above lines added to the files.

When I try to use this into the project by adding the following line in any of my .java files

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;

I get the following context error:

The type com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp is not accessible Java(16778666)

com.jcraft.jsch

```
When I try to compile it, i get the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        The type com.jcraft.jsch.JSch is not accessible
```

Stumped and don't know where to turn as I have added other jar files in the exact same way, and that worked.